# cross platform multitouch and graphics in Java with libgdx and mt4j

Tags: java, libgdx, multi-touch, mt4j

I have a cross platform application built with libgdx. The software is often used in conjunction with large touchscreens (like the microsoft coffee table thingy) with Windows (7 & 8) and MacOS. These screens are multitouch capable but I've only implemented single-touch, and would like to take the leap to multi.
I'm asking a few questions here in case someone knowledgeable could spare me a bunch of hours testing hypothesis that are undocumented and un-googleable AFAIK:

-does libgdx support the win7 multitouch interface? win8?

-if I must resort to mt4j, can it be used WITHOUT the 3d engine layer? Heck I don't even need gesture recognition, just the low level state of the fingers. There is no way I'm replacing 10000+ lines of libgdx with mt4j!

-has anyone tried sparsh-ui as an alternative to mt4j? Does it support win7 multitouch?

Thanks for any bit of information that can be provided on these matters!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there shouldn't be a problem with multitouch. For libgdx mouse presses and touches are the same thing, so there shouldn't be a problem for win7 and win8.
The `touchDown`, `touchUp` and `touchDragged` methods give you an `int pointer`, which describes the number of the touch. So if you touch with 4 fingers, the `touchDown` with `pointer = 4` describes the touch of the 4th finger.
You can read something about that [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Polling).
Note that i did not test this, as i don't have a win7/8 touch device. So you have to test it yourself, but as i said it should work. Let me know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: libgdx multitouch not working on win7, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924957/libgdx-multitouch-on-desktop-systems

Comment: @DarkDarker oh damn i did not think that the backend does not support that. Well then it does not matter if libgdx would support it... To bad...