# Libgdx multitouch on desktop systems

Tags: libgdx, multi-touch

I have a monitor with multi touch. It's possible to handle multi touch in libgdx on desktop systems(win7, osx...)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope.

Libgdx uses LWJGL as its desktop platform backend (*).  You can see in [LwjglInput.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglInput.java) that [`supportsMultitouch()`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglInput.java#L261) returns false, and that it hardcodes pointer numbers other than 0 as returning fixed values.

I think LWJGL would have to support multi-touch before Libgdx would be likely to use it.  (I'm not sure what the support for multi-touch events in LWJGL is.)  If you have some other system API for getting multi-touch events, it shouldn't be too hard to get `LwjglInput.java` to use it.

(*) There is also a JGLFW backend, but I don't think that is for public use (and I'm not sure if it makes multi-touch input any better).