# GestureListener Pinch and Zoom for desktop

Tags: libgdx

I've got a `Screen` with an `InputMultiplexer` that has a `GestureListener` added to it, however the `pinch` and `zoom` callback never fire.

The device I'm using is a touch screen laptop with Windows 8.1, and touching the screen does activate 'tap', 'pan', and 'panStop', so things are working, to an extent.  The documentation doesn't seem to mention that there is a restriction on the desktop and `GestureListener` combo.

Is there any way have the `zoom` and `pinch` callbacks fire while in a desktop Java application?

Comment: No, LibGDX does not support multi-touch on desktop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924957/libgdx-multitouch-on-desktop-systems